# why should I sometimes don't need to use 'get' while othertimes need to use 'get' for filtering?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to understand mapboxgl.js expression.

I understand that 'get' is used for getting value of a key in properties like the case of

```
 ['-', 2017, ['number', ['get', 'Constructi'], 2017]]
```

However in some cases, to get the value, I don't need to use 'get' like

```
function filterBy(month) {
var filters = ['==', 'month', month];
map.setFilter('earthquake-circles', filters);
map.setFilter('earthquake-labels', filters);
 
// Set the label to the month
document.getElementById('month').textContent = months[month];
}
```

In this case, I only need to type 'key' which is 'month'.

Why sometimes I have to use 'get' while other times it's okay to type just a key?

I tried to tweak the code from mapbox example.
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/

I wanted to show hovered polygon only.

So I added a line

```
map.on('mousemove', 'state-fills', function (e) {
            if (e.features.length > 0) {
                if (hoveredStateId !== null) {
                    map.setFeatureState(
                        { source: 'states', id: hoveredStateId },
                        { hover: false }
                    );
                }
                hoveredStateId = e.features[0].id;
                map.setFeatureState(
                    { source: 'states', id: hoveredStateId },
                    { hover: true }
                );
            }
          map.setFilter('state-fills',['==',['feature-state','hover'],true])

        });
```

It didn't work out so I assumed that "for some reason" I have to add 'get'.
So I tried

```
map.setFilter('state-fills',['==',['get',['feature-state','hover'] ],true])
```

It didn't work out either.
So I assumed that I might have to add 'boolean' instead of 'get' since it's evaluate if the retrieved value is true.

```
  map.setFilter('state-fills',['==',['boolean',['feature-state','hover'] ],true])
```

None of them were working.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `get` to access an attribute.

The version without `get` is an older syntax which is only partially supported. If you try to mix and match, you will get very confusing errors. For instance:

`filter: ['==', 'val', 1] // works`

`filter: ['==', ['get', 'val'], 2] // works`

`filter: ['any', ['==', 'val', 1'], ['==', ['get', 'val'], 2]] // doesn't work`

However, what you are doing here:

> `map.setFilter('state-fills',['==',['get',['feature-state','hover'] ],true])`

This is wrong, because `['feature-state','hover']` is not an attribute, it's a feature state.

You can't filter by feature-state.

### Solution 1

You probably want to do something like:

```js
map.setPaintProperty('state-fills', 'fill-opacity', ['case', ['to-boolean', ['feature-state','hover']], 1, 0.5]);
```

That is: use the feature-state to set fill opacity to 0.5 if the thing isn't hovered-over (or whatever).

### Solution 2

```js
map.setFilter('state-fills', ['==', ['id'], hoveredStateId]);
```

Comment: Super Clear! Thank you so much. Since filter doesn't support 'by feature-states', another option coming to my mind is changing geojson data and update like
//////////////////////////
        var foundIndex = jsondata.features.findIndex(x => x.id == targetId)
//////////////////////////
And then, 
//////////////////////////
        jsondata.features[foundIndex].properties.userData = 'hi'
//////////////////////////
Then update the source...
////////////////////////
        map.getSource('precinct').setData(jsondata)
////////////////////////
You think it would have performance issue?

Comment: Probably. I've added another possible solution for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I also think my approach might cause performance issue eventually. However, you didn't use 'get' in the solution 2. why? you just typed 'id' instead of ['get', 'id']. Why?

Comment: Because `id` is also not an attribute. It's a special identifier, and accessed through the special function `['id']`